# TFS On Premise security for merging pull requests

Tags: git, tfs, merge

Trying to set up security settings for a new on-premise install of Team Foundation Server (Version 15)

I have created a new TFS Group that I want to provide restricted access to. Group is called "Co-op Developer".

I was users within this group to be able to contribute to code; that is commit code to GIT branches. However, I do not want users within this group to be able to Merge Pull Requests.

As far as I can tell, in order for users in this group to be able to access and modify code I need to enable the Contribute access control for the repositories, as shown in this screenshot.

[image]

However, by doing so the user is able to merge pull requests.

How can i set this user up to be able to commit code to the repositories, but not allow these users to be able to perform a merge on a pull request.

Further to this question, I would also like to force a code review for any code committed by these users if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull requests let your team give feedback on changes in feature branches before merging the code into the master branch. There is not a distinctly pull request related in the [GIT permission](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/git-permissions-before-2017)  list.

However, you could use **branch policy** to achieve what you need.

> force a code review for any code committed by these users

After you set up a branch policy, you cannot directly push changes to the branch. **Changes to the branch are only made through pull requests.**

To require teams to review their changes before completing a pull request, select **Require a minimum number of approvals before completing pull request** under **Code review requirements**.

> set this user up to be able to commit code to the repositories, but
>   not allow these users to be able to perform a merge on a pull request

The owner cannot review and approve their own changes if **Allow users to approve their own changes** is not selected. Without the code review completed, then the user is not able to commit/merge changes in pull request.

More details about the branch policy please refer this tutorial: [**Improve code quality with branch policies**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-policies)